# Stream Webcam over HTTP in VLCj

Tags: java, http-live-streaming, live-streaming, vlcj, videochat

I am trying to create a video chat application in VLCj but am not able to successfully stream my webcam video over HTTP though an already downloaded video is streaming with help of the following code(command line argument fed as the file name) but this doesn't work if I give the command line argument as "dshow://" . How can I stream my webcam over the network over HTTP because RTP seems to be blocked over the network as even a downloaded file isn't getting streamed over RTP.

public class StreamHttp extends VlcjTest {

```
private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(VlcjTest.class);
private static final String NATIVE_LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATH = "C:\\Program Files\\VideoLAN\\VLC";
private static final String DUMP_NATIVE_MEMORY = "false";

static {
    // Initialise Log4J (this is good enough for testing, vlcj depends on log4j only for testing here)
    BasicConfigurator.configure();

    LibXUtil.initialise();

    if(null != NATIVE_LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATH) {
        logger.info("Explicitly adding JNA native library search path: '{}'", NATIVE_LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATH);
        NativeLibrary.addSearchPath(RuntimeUtil.getLibVlcLibraryName(), NATIVE_LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATH);
    }

    System.setProperty("jna.dump_memory", DUMP_NATIVE_MEMORY);
}


public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    if(args.length != 1) {
        System.out.println("Specify a single MRL to stream");
        System.exit(1);
    }

    String media = args[0];
    String options = formatHttpStream("10.3.1.31", 5555);

    System.out.println("Streaming '" + media + "' to '" + options + "'");

    MediaPlayerFactory mediaPlayerFactory = new MediaPlayerFactory(args);
    HeadlessMediaPlayer mediaPlayer = mediaPlayerFactory.newHeadlessMediaPlayer();
    mediaPlayer.playMedia(media, options);

    // Don't exit
    Thread.currentThread().join();
}

private static String formatHttpStream(String serverAddress, int serverPort) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(60);
    sb.append(":sout=#duplicate{dst=std{access=http,mux=ts,");
    sb.append("dst=");
    sb.append(serverAddress);
    sb.append(':');
    sb.append(serverPort);
    sb.append("}}");
    return sb.toString();
}
```

}

Comment: the vlcj test sources have a "ChatTest" example, does that work for you... if it doesn't, then your problem is likely not vlcj.

Comment: but in the ChatTest example the data is streamed over RTP and as I said , RTP is blocked over my LAN network hence i need to stream over HTTP if that's possible.

Comment: is the problem with your use of dshow, or http? because http streaming is very easy to set up in vlcj as per the StreamHttp example.

Comment: problem is in streaming dshow on HTTP. I am able to stream dshow on RTP and a downloaded video on HTTP but can't stream dshow over HTTP. I'll be grateful if you could help me implement this.